# SOAP object returning null from webservice.

Tags: c#, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

Dot net webservice is returning the complete arraylist. But response is not getting stored in soap object and count is always Zero.

```
SoapObject request=new SoapObject(Servicedata.NAMESPACE, Servicedata.METHOD_NAMECHAPTERLIST);

request.addProperty("Subject",Subject);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

envelope.dotNet=true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport=new HttpTransportSE(Servicedata.URL);

androidHttpTransport.call(Servicedata.SOAP_ACTIONCHAPTERLIST, envelope);

Chapterresultstr=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();  

Totalchapter=Chapterresultstr.getPropertyCount();

Log.e("Chapter",Integer.toString(Totalchapter));
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works :

```
Object resultsString = (Object)envelope.getResponse();

    String data = resultsString.toString();
```

Instead of

```
    Chapterresultstr=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();  

Totalchapter=Chapterresultstr.getPropertyCount();

Log.e("Chapter",Integer.toString(Totalchapter));
```

Comment: post your logcat then

Answer (score 0):

```
request.addProperty("Subject", Subject);
```

replace with

```
request.addProperty("arge1", Subject);
```

Soap in this way is not a good solution I recommend using HTTPS this way

Comment: If Request property is given statically in webservice then it value is returned in SOAP object. But I give it dynamically then it still returns NULL in SOAP object.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely ever use the SoapObject from `getResponse`. I usually just use `androidHttpTransport.responseDump` - which returns the raw XML and then parse the XML.

You could also try this tutorial for returning arrays from SOAP web service
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/web-service-that-returns-array-of.html